# Bubble sort not printing the correct thing

Tags: python, bubble-sort

This simple bubble sort works. However say that A = 45 and B = 23 how can I get it to print B, A instead of 24, 45. Thanks in advance.

```
a = input('Pick a number')
b = input('Pick a number')
c = input('Pick a number')
d = input('Pick a number')
e = input('Pick a number')

my_list = [a,b,c,d,e]

def bubble(bad_list):
    length = len(bad_list) - 1
    sorted = False

    while not sorted:
        sorted = True
        for i in range(length):
            if bad_list[i] > bad_list[i+1]:
                sorted = False
                bad_list[i], bad_list[i+1] = bad_list[i+1], bad_list[i]

bubble(my_list)
print (my_list)
```

Comment: What do you mean? you want the variable name instead of the value?

Comment: Your implementation does not work for `a=17`, `b=3`, `c=29`, `d=15` and `e=8`. It prints `['15', '17', '29', '3', '8']` which is not correctly sorted.

Comment: do `my_list = [int(i) for i in  [a,b,c,d,e]]`

Comment: @Guy yes i want the variable name instead of the value

Answer (score 2):

Provided the numbers are distinct, you can first take a copy of the list, and then look up the original position in the list and convert it to its corresponding letter:

```
initial_list = my_list.copy()
bubble(my_list)
print(my_list)
print ([["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"][initial_list.index(i)] for i in my_list])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a *list comprehension* to convert variables to `numbers`.

```
my_list = [int(input('Pick a number')) for _ in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it: instead of storing just the numbers in the list, store a pair which holds both the number, and the "name" of that item (i.e. the letter indicating its position in the original list).

```py
from collections import namedtuple
Item = namedtuple('Item', 'number letter')

my_list = []
for letter in 'abcde':
    number = int(input('Pick a number: '))
    my_list.append(Item(number, letter))

# ... bubble sort code works the same

bubble(my_list)

print([ item.letter for item in my_list ])
```

Example:

```
Pick a number: 5
Pick a number: 1
Pick a number: 3
Pick a number: 4
Pick a number: 2
['b', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'a']
```

The reason it works without changing your `bubble` function is because the items will be compared by `number`, since that's the first component of the tuple. In case two items have equal numbers, they will be compared by `letter`, and not swapped because the first letter will always be less than the second letter; that's correct because bubble sort shouldn't swap equal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are unique, you can make a dictionary containing variable names as keys, and variable values as dictionary values, as follows :

```
my_dict = {'a' : a, 'b' : b, 'c' : c, 'd' : d, 'e' : e}
```

This should be done before calling the `bubble()` function. When sorting is done, simply do

```
def get_key(val): 
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        if val == int(value): 
            return key
for i in my_list:
    print(get_key(i), end = ', ')
```

This will output

```
a, b, c, d, e,
```

Comment: Where is `get_key` defined?

Comment: I'm really sorry, my bad! I've edited the code with get_key() function

Comment: If your values are unique, it would make more sense to do `my_dict = {a: 'a', ...}` and then `print(my_dict[i], end=', ')` without the need for `get_key`.

Comment: Yes, that makes it easier, A better way, definitely!